# Controlling an RC car

Tags: voltage, pcb, signal, ground

I 'm planning on controlling an RC car via ΒeagleBoard-xM. Pistol transmitter uses ic [TX2 encoder](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWW/CD13/GV525G0X/FWWCD13GV525G0X.pdf).

As image shows, right-left commands are implemented by a 3-part conductive area. Specifically, when area "R" gets grounded, a signal for right rotation is being transmitted. When area "L" gets grounded, a signal for left rotation is being transmitted.

The idea is BeagleBoard-xM to send these signals by two different GPIO ports. Presence of voltage in GPIO port, means signal to be transmitted. However, when I connected two wires for right rotation (one in conductive area "R" and the other to GNG) signal has been transmitted when I powered supply the circuit. This makes sense, as area "R" was already grounded.

The aim is a signal to be transmitted, when wire in conductive area "R" has voltage by BeagleBoard-xM. Is something like this possible?

[image]

Comment: Got a couple of NPNs or NMOSFETs handy?

Comment: Is a schematic design possible? If I understood, when there is a signal, conductive area "R" gets grounded, otherwise not?

Comment: And N-type devices are used to pull connections to ground (see: "low-side driver"). Which N-type device you need depends on the characteristics of the signal and connection.

Comment: The collector goes to the "R" connection. And you *need* a resistor on the base since pulling the base high will result in putting Vcc and Vbe in parallel. Not a good thing. You'll get Ice(sat)(max), hfe(min), and Vbe(max) from the transistor datasheet and Vout(max) from the MCU datasheet, so you'll need to calculate Ib(min) and hence Rb(max).

Comment: Just for confirmation: Ice(sat)(max) is the same as Ic (maximum rating)? As transistor voltage supply, I consider Vout(max) from MCU, which connects to the Base. Can I power supply  Collector, by connecting it with pin 9 (VDD pin of the ic TX2)?

Comment: I was wrong about Ice(sat)(max). It should instead be I(pad), the current from the pad to ground when they are short circuited. Use an ammeter to measure this. You don't want to connect the collector to your power supply; the purpose of the transistor is to create a connection between the R and L pads and the ground. The collector should connect to the R or L pad.

Answer (score 1):

Simple optocouplers will do the the trick (for instance MOCD217M, dual optocoupler, ~ $1 per unit). Basically, an optocoupler is a light-based relay  and can be controlled from low power outputs, such as GPIOs. Using optocouplers will make sure that the emitter and the BeagleBoard electronics wont mess which each-other.